# What to do when ovtest and linktest in Stata suggest model misspecification?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, least-squares, stata, misspecification

I have a sample that consists of 50 observations. The base model of the OLS-Regression with three control variables, two of them significant, has a $R^2=0.50$ and its F-Value is 7. Both `–ovtest` and `–linktest` (Stata 10.0) indicate no model misspecification.

I am testing four Hypotheses. However, after having included the four variables – two of them significant - in the regression, the –ovtest and –linktest (Stata Version 10.0) indicate a model misspecification. I did regression diagnostics, which lead to the removal of three outliers because of their influence and a violation of the assumption that the residuals are normally distributed. With all seven variables in the model, $R^2$ is 0.65 (Huber-White robust standard errors) and the F-Value is 7. Even if I add only the two significant independent variables, both tests are failing, i.e. the ovtest, for example, rejects the H0 that the model has no omitted variables.

So my question is: what can I possibly do to improve matters?

I read that the `ovtest` is critical for proceeding with the analysis, but I cannot detect any further violation of regression assumptions. Dropping the variables is no alternative, since they are the ones of theoretical interest.

Edit: I added three observed vs. fitted plots

1) 50 Observations, 7 variables

2) 47 Observations (without 10,12,48), 3 variables

3) 47 Observations (without 10,12,48), 7 variables

[image: 50 Observations , 7 variables]

[image: 47 Observations (without 10,12,48), 3 variables]

[image: 47 Observations (without 10,12,48), 7 variables]

Comment: Have you computed and plotted the residuals?  Also, concerning `linktest`, have you read through the manual page (r.pdf) on it?  Example 2 is especially illuminating.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To your first question, yes I did. This was actually the reason why I calculated the final model without three of the observations. To your second question, I looked at the example you mentioned in the manual but there is no obvious transformation for my dependent variable that will fix the problem. I also tried the ladder command but no better alternative is suggested.

Comment: These are strange-looking scatterplots, Lars.  I suspect the specification tests fail in the third instance due to the pronounced curvature of that little trace of dots near the upper right, where the residuals become very small (and almost half the cases occur).  It leaves one wondering about why this happens: why is it that in half the cases there is a small range of fitted values and a nearly perfect fit (compared to the other values)?  Can you find an explanation?