# Linktest results interpretation

Tags: interpretation, stata, misspecification

`linktest`'s rule of thumb is that `_hat` should be statistically significant while `_hatsq` should not be significant, in order for the model to be called "correctly specified".

However, when I did run `linktest` in Stata, I got both insignificant `_hat` and `_hatsq`. How should I interpret this result?

Answer (score 1):

> A model specification error can occur when one or more relevant variables are omitted from the model or one or more irrelevant variables are included in the model. If relevant variables are omitted from the model, the common variance they share with included variables may be wrongly attributed to those variables, and the error term is inflated. On the other hand, if irrelevant variables are included in the model, the common variance they share with included variables may be wrongly attributed to them. Model specification errors can substantially affect the estimate of regression coefficients.

> The linktest command performs a model specification link test for single-equation models. linktest is based on the idea that if a regression is properly specified, one should not be able to find any additional independent variables that are significant except by chance. linktest creates two new variables, the variable of prediction, _hat, and the variable of squared prediction, _hatsq. The model is then refit using these two variables as predictors. _hat should be significant since it is the predicted value. On the other hand, _hatsq shouldn’t, because if our model is specified correctly, the squared predictions should not have much explanatory power. That is we wouldn’t  expect  _hatsq to be a significant predictor if our model is specified correctly.

[https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter2/stata-webbooksregressionwith-statachapter-2-regression-diagnostics/]

Also from the same source, you can test for omitted variables:

> The ovtest command performs another test of regression model specification. It performs a regression specification error test (RESET) for omitted variables. The idea behind ovtest is very similar to linktest. It also creates new variables based on the predictors and refits the model using those new variables to see if any of them would be significant.

As per the comments in this similar question, plotting residuals may help show patterns in the current model, for example quadratic effects. Thereafter understanding how your model changes by adding, modifying or removing variables is a next step. Also consider whether interaction terms may be useful.

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19794/what-to-do-when-ovtest-and-linktest-in-stata-suggest-model-misspecification]

@whuber mentions example 2 of the Stata manual, and this transforms the dependent variable, which is another option to help the model fit the reality better. From the manual:

> For those with an engineering background, mpg is indeed a strange measure. It would make more sense to model energy consumption—gallons per mile—in terms of weight and displacement.